# EnableModelessKeyboardInterop or WindowInteropHelper when opening a WPF window from a Winforms app

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms, interop

I have a winforms application opening a wpf window. I've used both methods below:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(window)
```

and

```
Dim helper As System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper = New System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(window)
helper.Owner = Me.Handle
```

I've opted to use the second method, as the application, in random occasions, will fail to display the content of the wpf window, and even crash it. This will occur in different environments (32/64) with xp or 7, and unfortunately, I was never able to reproduce it in development. This window only uses a datagrid, with some interaction done via button controls. Anyways, by switching over to the second method, it seemed to have corrected the issue altogether. The bug has not manifested for months now.  However, now I’m adding a textbox control to this window, and noticed that it’s not allowing the text entry, only spaces.  If I switch back to the original method, it works, but I’m afraid the issue will start showing up in production again.  Has someone come across this issue before?  Any advice will be greatly appreciated!